# Why is the Lagrangian $-\partial^u\overline\Psi\partial_u\Psi-m^2\overline\Psi\Psi$ not Lorentz invariant?

Tags: special-relativity, lagrangian-formalism, field-theory, lorentz-symmetry, dirac-equation

Let $-\partial^u\overline\Psi\partial_u\Psi-m^2\overline\Psi\Psi$ be a Lagrangian density. Here $\Psi$ is the Dirac spinor and $\overline \Psi$ is defined to be $\Psi^\dagger \gamma^0$. It is said that this Lagrangian is not Lorentz invariant. However, I cannot see why. For me, it has perfect form of being Lorentz invariant. Could anyone please explain why this Lagrangian is not Lorentz invariant?

Comment: "It is said" by whom?

Comment: It's a dimension 5 term

Comment: @AccodentalFourierTransform  my lecturer

Comment: @Keith Perhaps it was a slip of the tongue. The Lagrangian is Lorentz invariant, but not renormalizable (in four dimensions).

Comment: @gj255 It is renormalizable in any dimensions. The first term in N dimensions would imply $\Psi$ to be in dimensions $GeV^{N/2-1}$ which is the same for the second term because of the squared mass. It looks like a Klein-Gordon equation but has a four-component field with mixed energy eigenstates?

Comment: @OktayDoğangün Hmm,  yes perhaps you're right.

Answer (score 2):

Let us first agree on the fact that $\bar{\psi}\psi$ is indeed a Lorentz invariant, so the mass term obviously is. For the second term, you could integrate by parts arrive to:
$$\bar{\psi}(\Box - m^2)\psi$$ 
which is again Lorentz invariant since $\Box$ also is. Here the $\gamma^0$ is causing kinetic mixing originally if you want, but it looks Lorentz invariant.

So, I would say it looks like a weird mixture of 4 Klein Gordon fields. If you compute the equations of motion it seems every component of what you called a "Dirac spinor" satisfies a Klein-Gordon equation. If you are given this equation there is nothing forcing them to be Dirac spinors.

EDIT: What people are saying in the comments about 5th dimension operators is also true if you assume beforehand that those fields have the mass dimensions of a Dirac field, namely 3/2. But then again it makes no sense to declare them Dirac fields if there is no $\bar{\psi}\gamma^\mu\partial_\mu \psi$ term.